# Create search articles feature in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

First of all, let me tell you that I'm a novice in the world of javascript and node.js. I have been searching for help in trying to do what i want but haven't found yet.

I am using the MEAN stack(http://mean.io/) and I am trying to implement a search feature in the included articles model. The search would look for articles with a specific tag and would be implemented in the index page. Follow me and see if you can find what I am missing please.

**In the backend:**

app/models/

```
/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    tag: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

app/controllers/

```
exports.searcharticle = function(req, res) {
    Article.find({'tag': req.params.tag}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

Added the route for the search in app/routes/articles.js

```
app.get('/articles/search/:tag', articles.searcharticle);
```

**In the frontend:**

Created the view for the search wich will display the search results - public/views/articles/search.html

```
<section data-ng-controller="ArticlesController" data-ng-init="searchart()">
<ul class="articles unstyled">
<li data-ng-repeat="article in articles">
<span>{{article.created | date:'medium'}}</span> /
<span>{{article.user.name}}</span>
<h2><a data-ng-href="#!/articles/{{article._id}}">{{article.name}}</a></h2>
<div>{{article.tag}}</div>
</li>
</ul>
<h1 data-ng-hide="!articles || articles.length">Your search hasn't returned any results. <br> Why don't you <a href="/#!/articles/create">Create One</a>?</h1>
</section>
```

The view for the index.html, where the searchbox will be implemented

```
<section data-ng-controller="ArticlesController">
      <form role="form" data-ng-submit="searchart()">
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="tag" ng-model="selected" class="form-control" placeholder="Tag">
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </form>
```

Added the route to the config.js

```
when('/articles/search/:tag', {
            templateUrl: 'views/articles/search.html'
        }).
```

And added the search function to the articles controller

```
$scope.searchart = function() {
    Articles.query(function(articles) {
        $scope.articles = articles;
    });
};
```

Right now, with this code implemented, when I click in the submit button in the index page, nothing happens.

Can you find what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a URL in your client Article Service, you should define the URL Parameter in the articles service at: packages/articles/public/services/article.js, like the articleId parameter already defined in there like this:

```
angular.module('mean.articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles/:articleId', {
      articleId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Then you need to pass it in your angular controller search method, like the function that gets one by id, like this:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
      Articles.get({
        articleId: $stateParams.articleId
      }, function(article) {
        $scope.article = article;
      });
    };
```

Personally I don't know how to add another parameter to the $resource object in addition to the existing one (articleId), you may have to create another $resource service with the new parameter (:tag) and use it in your search method in your angular controller.

**Another way** that sounds more simple and flexible to me is to just pass the search parameters in the query method, like this:

```
 $scope.searchart = function() {
    Articles.query({tag:$scope.selectedTag}, function(articles) {
        $scope.articles = articles;
    });
};
```

and then at the server side controller, read your query parameters like this:

```
exports.searcharticle = function(req, res) {
    Article.find(req.query).sort('-created').populate('user', 'name username').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(articles);
        }
    });
};
```