# Implementing Search option in Mean Stack Application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, search, elasticsearch

Can someone please suggest how  to implement a search feature in the application built using angularjs,nodejs and mongodb this feature should be like when a user enters letter a then all the book names which is starting with a from the database should be displayed in the drop down (eg: tags drop down below in stack overflow)

Any suggestion and help?

Comment: Do you want typeahead autocomplete or just search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661030/create-search-articles-feature-in-mean-stack – you can find similar question here

Comment: i need typeahead autocomplete

Answer (score -1):

You can have a web service running such that a REST api call from angular is made to your web service whenever some one presses a letter in the search box.

The web service code should handle querying the database and sending the results.

You can use a cache to make it faster